# Does LU factorization needs pivoting?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Today I have a numerical methods exam,and of course i tried some exercices, but today I heard something that messed my mind,
I always do LU fact. Like this :

I take Lower triangular matrix, and then upper one with the 1s on the diameter, I calculate the product of two matrices and set equal to the matrix that I want to  factorize, so does this process need a pivoting? If yes how? If we move a row in our original matrix it will affect our calculations and of course we get a wrong answer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* there are $L,U$  such that  $A=LU$, then you find them without pivoting.

However, not all (invertible) matrices admit an LU decomposition. 
For this case there os a related method with pivoting, sometimes called LUP.

See [the Wikipedia page of LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) for details on.

Comment: I would add that pivoting _is_ necessary for numerical stability for many classes of matrices.